# iOS Keychain - LAContext.setCredential(data, .applicationPassword) returns false on Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I am trying to use an "applicationPassword" to protect the data that a user stores in the Keychain.

Everything works perfectly on a *real device* but unfortunately things don't work at all on the simulator.

In order to get started I have this very basic code to set the applicationPassword.

```
let authenticationContext = LAContext()
let applicationPassword = "123".data(using: .utf8)
let result = authenticationContext.setCredential(applicationPassword, type: .applicationPassword)
print(result)
```

The call to `setCredential` returns `true` on a real device but `false` on the simulator.

Please help :-)

If this isn't supported on the Simulator then it isn't really a feasible solution.

Here is Apple's documentation, for reference:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/1514168-setcredential

Comment: On the simulator make sure you are enrolled in faceId/TouchId under Hardware menu

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `setCredential` has nothing to do with biometrics (faceID or touchID) so I wouldn't have expected this to make a difference.  I have tried as suggested and the call still returns `false`.

Comment: On simulator it will not work properly, had same issue

Answer (score 4):

It would seem that `applicationPassword` works in conjunction with the device's **system passcode**.

And therefore an `applicationPassword` will NOT work on:

- The simulator (where its not possible to set a system passcode)
- A real device without a system passcode set

I have ascertained this information from the below souces:

---

[WWDC 2015 - Session 706 - Security & Your Apps](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/706/) (see around 43:23 of video)

Transcript: https://asciiwwdc.com/2015/sessions/706?q=applicationpassword

> Now, let's look at an item protected with ApplicationPassword.
>
> Just the device passcode is no longer sufficient.
>
> Your application has also got to provide its own password.
>
> Again, we derive a cryptographic key from it, and it's only when the
>   device passcode and the app password are both present that access is
>   granted to the Keychain item.

---

https://nabla-c0d3.github.io/blog/2015/06/16/ios9-security-privacy/

> Keychain items can now be encrypted using both the device’s passcode
>   and an “Application password”; both values are then needed to decrypt
>   and retrieve the item. This allows Apps to control when the data is
>   accessible/decrypted, instead of having the data decrypted as soon as
>   the device is unlocked.

---

https://macbirdie.net/2016/03/app-pwd

> The other interesting new feature is securing the keychain items using
>   an application-provided password, which is an additional factor to
>   device unlock PIN or passcode.
>
> The password can either come from the user or, as the session 706’s
>   presenter suggested, either can be an additional token sent by the
>   server or a secret kept on a device connected to the phone.
>
> This security scheme requires at least a device passcode to exist,
>   since it works with it in tandem. As a result of that it’s not
>   possible to test it on the iOS Simulator, which makes developing the
>   support for it a little harder, because when you add a keychain item
>   protected that way, no actual password is even required to retrieve
>   it.

---

Its a shame that none of Apple's own documention seems to make a mention of this:

- [Apple - setCredential(_:type:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/1514168-setcredential)
- [Apple - LACredentialType.applicationPassword](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacredentialtype/applicationpassword)
- [Apple - applicationPassword](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/secaccesscontrolcreateflags/1617930-applicationpassword)
- [Apple - Restricting Keychain Item Accessibility](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/restricting_keychain_item_accessibility)

Comment: Hmm, for me it works perfectly fine on a real device with passcode turned off.